# Adding up all median lengths of a triangle not exceeding perimeter?

Tags: geometry

When adding up all lengths of the medians of a triangle, why does the result not exceed perimeter?

Answer (score 3):

Let $D,E,F$ be the midpoints of $BC,CA,AB$ respectively

**Hint:** Apply the triangle inequality to triangles $ADE$, $BEF$ and $CFD$.

Use the fact that $|DE| = \frac{|AB|}{2}$ since they are midpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property that in a triangle ABC if AD , BE and CF are the three medians
then 2AD ≤ AB + AC
     2BE ≤ BC +BA
     2CF ≤ CA +CB
Add
     AD + BE + CF ≤ AB + BC +AC

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you state your reasoning a little more elaborately ?